# Confidence Interval Inequality Simplification

Tags: probability, inequality, confidence-interval

In the [Wikipedia for Hoeffding's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#Confidence_intervals), it says that $\alpha \leq 2e^{-2\varepsilon^2n}$ implies that $n \geq \frac{\log(2/\alpha)}{2\varepsilon^2}$. When I work through the intermediate steps, I get an inequality flip from dividing by a negative:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &\frac{\alpha}{2} \leq e^{-2\varepsilon^2n} \\
    \implies &\log(\frac{2}{\alpha}) \geq 2\varepsilon^2n \\
    \implies &\frac{\log(2/\alpha)}{2\varepsilon^2} \geq n.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
What am I missing?

Comment: It has an opposite meaning, when $n\ge n(\alpha)=\log(2/\alpha)/2\epsilon^2$, we have less than probability of $\alpha$ that the estimated $p$ does not belong to the $\epsilon$-neighbor of real $p$, oppositely it means we have more than probability of $1-\alpha$ to believe that estimated $p$ can be located in the $\epsilon$-neighbor of real $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasing in Wikipedia is a bit misleading. Instead of writing
$$ \alpha = P(\bar X \notin [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]) $$
what we are actually looking for is a **sufficient** condition for
$$ P(\bar X \notin [p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon]) \leq \alpha .$$
Since the probability on the left is smaller than $2e^{-2\epsilon^2 n}$, it is enough to ensure that
$$ 2e^{-2\epsilon^2 n} \leq \alpha . $$
From there you can obtain Wikipedia’s inequality.